# No goals have been specified for this build

Tags: java, linux, command-line, maven-3

I'm trying to create a project using Project-generator.jar from Linux terminal. I'm using command

```
java -jar project-generator.jar
```

at last step this is showing error

```
[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. 
You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the 
format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. 
Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources,
process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes,
generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, 
process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, 
prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, 
post-integration-test, verify, шnstall, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, 
pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.NoGoalSpecifiedException: 
No goals have been specified to create a project using Project-generaotot.jar 
from Linux terminal.
```

Comment: So what would you like to know? What is the question? Your command is user specific and has nothing to do with Maven?

Comment: I want to know where I need to provide the goal as thete is no any pom.xml created. I have used java -jar project-generator.jar clean  but this command is showing that no any target folder present? any idea?

Comment: What's this `project-generator.jar`? Pls add a link to the project. It is definitely an issue with the tool you're trying to run, you should contact their support. I suspect they use Maven in the background but in a way that causes problem on your specific environment/platform/etc.