# How to fix this no goals have been specified for this build on maven?

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to build this maven project:

1. https://github.com/jottinger/owlapi-tutorial

Within this maven:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.autumncode</groupId>
    <artifactId>owlapi-tutorial</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
                <artifactId>owlapi-distribution</artifactId>
                <version>[4.0.2,)</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
                <artifactId>owlapi-rio</artifactId>
                <version>[4.0.2,)</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
                <artifactId>jfact</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.7</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                <version>[6.9.8,)</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>owlapi-distribution</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>owlapi-rio</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfact</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I found some questions about it as:

1. [No goals have been specified for this build.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41261750/no-goals-have-been-specified-for-this-build)
2. [maven - j2objc - No goals have been specified for this build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35851452/maven-j2objc-no-goals-have-been-specified-for-this-build)
3. [No goals have been specified for this build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21332109/no-goals-have-been-specified-for-this-build)
4. [Maven how to find out what settings.xml is used (Ubuntu)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43804301/maven-how-to-find-out-what-settings-xml-is-used-ubuntu)
5. [How to fix this Build Path Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772764/how-to-fix-this-build-path-error)
6. [How to fix this maven warning on Eclipse: "There is no schema defined for this pom.xml"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37489985/how-to-fix-this-maven-warning-on-eclipse-there-is-no-schema-defined-for-this-p)

They are saying I need to set a goal as:

```
  <goals>
    <goal>exploded</goal>
  </goals>
```

But I do not know how to put it in the configuration file above. This is the full log output when running the initial `pom.xml`:

```
mvn -e -X
Apache Maven 3.5.0 (ff8f5e7444045639af65f6095c62210b5713f426; 2017-04-03T16:39:06-03:00)
Maven home: D:\User\Documents\apache_marven\maven
Java version: 1.8.0_131, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "x86", family: "windows"
[DEBUG] Created new class realm maven.api
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm maven.api
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.util.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.classrealm < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.cli < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.exception < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution.scope < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.model < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.monitor < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.plugin < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.profiles < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.project < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.reporting < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.rtinfo < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.settings < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.toolchain < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.usability < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authentication < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.events < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.observers < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.proxy < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.resource < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.component < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.container < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.context < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.logging < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.personality < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParser < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlSerializer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.collection < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.deployment < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.graph < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.installation < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.metadata < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.resolution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.spi < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.transfer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.version < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.fusesource.jansi.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.helpers.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.spi.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG] Populating class realm maven.api
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Message scheme: color
[DEBUG] Message styles: debug info warning error success failure strong mojo project
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from D:\User\Documents\apache_marven\maven\conf\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from C:\Users\Professional\.m2\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading global toolchains from D:\User\Documents\apache_marven\maven\conf\toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user toolchains from C:\Users\Professional\.m2\toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at C:\Users\Professional\.m2\repository
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for C:\Users\Professional\.m2\repository
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.mycompany.app:my-app:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecycle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.445 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-05-05T23:05:24-03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.NoGoalSpecifiedException: No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy.
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:94)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoGoalSpecifiedException
```

I would not like to run it from eclipse. I would prefer just to call on the command line `mvn`, as I am currently doing.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The goal can be specified in the build-plugins-plugin section of your `pom.xml`, depending on what you want to happen with the application.

E.g. if you want to execute it, you can follow the steps described on the question  [How do I execute a program using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472376/how-do-i-execute-a-program-using-maven).

I don't think you can do it with just `mvn`, but you need to specify what happens (like `mvn package` or `mvn install`)

You can read more about goals and phases on [Introduction to the Build Lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html).

Comment: I was able to get mvn install to be my default by adding "<defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>" to my build section. just running mvn now does install.

Comment: I found this worked for me. In the "Edit Configuration" dialogue window, select spring-boot:run for the "Command Line", click Apply and OK. then you should be good to go.

Answer (score 42):

Enter the required life cycle event in *Command line* field in **run/debug configurations**.
For me, I want to run the project so, I used **spring-boot:run**

It worked for me

[Maven life cycle references](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference)

[image]

Comment: Thanks Buddy it worked like  charm, I was frustrated.

Answer (score 5):

Run the following command in cmd:
`mvn clean`

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with Jenkins + maven go to job->build-> and add Goals and option:

```
clean install -Denvironment="$"environment
```

[image]

Comment: What does this do? Could you please add explanation?

Answer (score 1):

For me below solution worked.
Go to terminal and run "mvn clean install"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26763729)

Comment: @NicolasBousquet He has provided an solution to this question.

Answer (score 0):

To have a clear example, you can run you application with **`mvn package exec:java`** by using the **`exec-maven-plugin`**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>com.path.to.MainFile</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

1. The **`com.path.to.MainFile`** file would be located on **`/src/main/java/com/path/to/MainFile.java`**